# Removing webpart from gallery breaks existing pages?

Tags: 2010, web-part, internet-explorer

I have one webpart that is breaking some of my pages and I don't want it to be available on the gallery for adding it to a page however I have some pages where I do use the webpart, my question is: If I remove the webpart from the gallery will it break the pages that are currently using it or it will only make it unavailable for adding it on any other page (which is what I would expect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove it from the gallery then the webpart shouldnt be available in the list and it shouldnt break the pages that are currently using it .

If you want that feature where you only want it on specific pages then you should look into making your webpart wrapped into a feature where you can set the scope and activate the feature to that specific scope instead :)

hope it helps :)